# laravel flash message isn't working inside exception

Tags: laravel, exception, flash-message

flash message isn't displayed when is in a catch exception

```
    try{
        if ($client->delete()) {
            $request->session()->flash('success', 'ok');
        } else {
            $request->session()->flash('error_flash', 'nok');
        }
    }catch(QueryException $e){            
        $request->session()->flash('error_flash', $e->getMessage());
    }
    return redirect()->route('clients');
```

Comment: Put a `\Log::info("Called");` statement in your `catch()` block to see if you're actually catching that exception. Consider changing `QueryException` to a more general `Exception`. Also, make sure `use \Illuminate\Database\QueryException;` is defined at the top of your page. Gotta do some self-debugging here.

Comment: I put a die function inside catch braces and when I force false in if the flash message works well

Comment: If you put a `die()` function in your catch, you wouldn't see the flash message... Y'know, cause of it being dead.

Comment: I put a die just to see that is entering inside catch block... I don't put the die function forever...